# character string or string constant

Tags: c, string

I am reading the book "The C Programming Language" by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie.

They talk about "character string" and "string constant". What is the difference between these concepts?

Answer (score 2):

1. A character constant consists of a single characters enclosed within single inverted commas.
2. A string constant may consist of any combination of digits, letters, escaped sequences and spaces, a sequence of characters enclosed in double quotes.

Check out this [link](http://aboutc.weebly.com/string-constants.html) 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A *string constant* is a sequence of characters enclosed in double quotes. A *character string* is a sequence of characters ending with '\0' stored in a character array or pointed to by a character pointer.

Example:

```
#include <string.h>

char s[4];

strcpy(s, "foo"); /*"foo" is a string constant and s contains a character string*/
```

Answer (score 0):

string constant:
Text enclosed in double quote characters (such as "example" ) is a string constant.

Character String:
Strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters terminated by a null character '\0'.
So basically the difference is character String is the object and string constant is the way to representation.